# How to make my pipeline stop deleting containers?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I have a Docker image with mysql and I am trying to use Jenkins to automatically update my image when GitHub is updated, this is the command I am using.

```
 pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Docker') {
      parallel {
        stage('limpar historico') {
          agent any
          steps {
            sh 'docker volume prune -f'
          }
        }
        stage('Docker') {
          agent any
          steps {
            script {
              def imagembonitinha = docker.build("imagembonitinha:latest", "./DockerBanco")
              imagembonitinha.run('-e "LANG=C.UTF-8" -e "LC_ALL=C.UTF-8" -it --rm --name "contbonito"  --network "banco" -p "3306:3306" -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234abcd"')
              docker.withRegistry('https://localhost:5000') {
              }
            }
            sh "docker start contbonito"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when Jenkins stops running it deletes my container. How can I make sure Jenkins keeps my container after I stop it?

Comment: Is the container actually starting up?  The `--rm` option says to delete the container once it exits, so if the main container process finishes, Docker (not Jenkins) deletes the container.  That's not bad, since the container is just a wrapper around the process, and you can `docker run` a new container from the built image.

Comment: I'm not sure but I would try using native docker commands through shell rather than docker plugin you are using.